# Only loading UIImage data used

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiimage

I have a 400 pattern images at 400x300 bundled within my app. I would like to make some kind of factory method to take a portion of that image and load them into UIImageViews. I've had some success with using content mode and clipping to bounds, but when I load a ton of these into a view it can take upwards of 5 seconds for the view to load. Here is an example of my current method.

```
UIImageView *tinyImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed@"400x300testImage.png"];
[tinyImageView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, 200)];
[tinyImageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeTopLeft];
[tinyImageView setClipsToBounds:YES];
[self.tinyImagesView addSubview:tinyImageView];
```

I've been reading the ImageIO class files and I think my answer is in there but I'm having a hard time putting together workable code. In another stackoverflow question I came across this code

```
CFDictionaryRef options = (__bridge CFDictionaryRef)[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                (id)kCFBooleanTrue, (id)kCGImageSourceCreateThumbnailWithTransform, 
                                                (id)kCFBooleanTrue, (id)kCGImageSourceCreateThumbnailFromImageIfAbsent, 
                                                (id)[NSNumber numberWithFloat:200.0f], (id)kCGImageSourceThumbnailMaxPixelSize, 
                                                nil];
    CGImageRef imgRef = CGImageSourceCreateThumbnailAtIndex(imageSource, 0, options);

    UIImage *scaled = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imgRef];

    CGImageRelease(imgRef);
    CFRelease(imageSource);

    return scaled;
```

This has a similar load time to loading the full images and clipping.

Is it possible to read in only a 10x200 strip of an image file and load that into a UIImageView that is as fast as creating that 10x200 png and loading that using imageNamed?

Comment: Can you show us one of the 400x300 images?  What exactly are you doing with the strips?  You mentioned patterns, if you are trying to tile patterns, you will get better performance with larger tiles.

Comment: I can't show the specific images used, but I can say it's much like a wood grain. It's a non-repeated pattern that won't scale well. The strips are used like thumbnails to identify a small portion of the whole image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure what you really want is a `CATiledLayer`, where you can point it at the set of images and have it automatically pull up what it needs.

You can just add a `CATiledLayer` to any `UIView`.

Comment: This seems to be the best idea to get around the problem, but I'd still like to know why you can't partially load an image. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I would not say it's getting around anything though, it's the best solution to what you are trying to do.